# Methods on passing code from one php page to another

Tags: php, session, include, require

I'm sorry if this is a simple question, I'm fairly new to php!

Anyhow, my issue is the following: I have a few lines of code on one page, in which I use mysql, html and php, and I would like to pass it onto another php page. What I was thinking at first is that I would use $_SESSION, but while that worked normally with text/variables, it didn't work with more extensive code. I'm supposing it's not made for that. The other alternative that I had thought of was to use the include/require functions, but that would mean taking the entire page of code, although I only need a small portion of it. What are my options?

For example, if I had the following:

```
<html>
<table>
<td><select name="Example">
<?php
while ($example_variable=mysqli_fetch_array($example_mysql_select)){
echo "<option>" . $example_variable['field'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</html>
```

... it wouldn't work with session. Do I have any alternatives, or am I stuck with require/include? Are there any ways of getting session to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: just create a page that contain **only** what you want, and `include()` it.

Comment: @Charlie that would be my "plan B". Put simply, everything would be much more organized if I were to do it without having to separate my code in different pages. Thanks anyways.

Comment: if you are trying pass code where there is logic operation, not variable or constant, then `include()` or `require()` is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Try serializing it:

```
$_SESSION['var'] = serialize($var);
```

Then access it with:

```
 $var = unserialize($_SESSION['var']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how I would get all the code into that? I took a look over the documentation, but I'm still not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple function on one PHP page:

```
function db_fetch($example_mysql_select){
    return mysqli_fetch_array($example_mysql_select)
}
```

From your HTML page, simply use:

```
<html>
 <table>
  <td>
    <select name="Example">
    <?php echo "<option>" . db_fetch($example_mysql_select) . "</option>"; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't change much because I would need to add the entire code (HTML included) in the session. On the other hand, would I be able to add the whole thing into a function, and then, would I be able to add the function in a session?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you really need @TudorManole. Are you trying to include the HTML in the function as well? And no, you cannot add a function to a session.